# Python - Finding unique group occurrence (regex).

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyse an apache access log file and I've managed to use regex to split up the parts I'm interested. I'm trying to find the number of unique IPs in the log(host only).

```
        for line in log.splitlines():
           result = pattern.match(line)
           IPs = list(result.groups()[0])
           print len(set(IPs))
```

I'm quite lost at this point. I can't seem to get the IPs in a form where I can use len() to get the size and set(IPs) to get rid of the reoccurring ones. I realise the code above is wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the log look like? What is `pattern`? What do you get instead of your desired result? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I went through the file line by line, grabbing the IPs using my pattern and adding them to a large list declared before. Then using len(set(IPs)) at the end outside the loop.